# How to create different objects by using inner class

Tags: oop, phaser-framework

Recently, I am learning Phaser 3 to build a game, and using Typescript to write the code.
besides, I am trying to create different objects by using Object-oriented programming inside Phaser class.

The code I wrote is below:

```js
class DifferentGraphics extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: "DifferentGraphics"
    });
  }

  create() {
    class Graphic {
      graphic: Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics;
      graphicAdd() {
        this.graphic.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
        this.graphic.fillStyle(0xffffff);
      }
    }

    let GraphicA = new Graphic();
    GraphicA.graphicAdd();
  }
}
```

Compiler didn’t show any Typescript error, but the browser displayed “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ’ fillRect ’ of undefined” after running the code.

I don’t know what’s wrong with my code?
If anyone can share your ideas or solutions, I will appreciate it.

The target I wanna achieve is to make 3 different objects, and these objects have different colors, sizes, positions, and methods that can tween the size separately by using Object-oriented programming.

How can I do to make it happen?
I need a direction or suggestion

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this.graphic is not initialized

You must initialize this.graphic in constructor, e.g

```
class Graphic {
    graphic: Phaser.GameObjects.Graphics;

   constructor(scene){
     this.graphic = scene.add.graphics(0,0);
   }

    graphicAdd() {
        this.graphic.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
         this.graphic.fillStyle(0xffffff);
        }

   }
```

then `let GraphicA = new Graphic(this);`